# Songs are getting repeated in iPod shuffle

Tags: ipod

My iPod Shuffle keeps on repeating only about 10 songs eventhough I have loaded about 125 songs.

This is happening when I keep in both 'Normal' & 'Shuffle' mode.

Could someone pls help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You should connect your iPod to itunes and make sure that the other 350 songs are really there and in a format that the iPod can play.
Sometimes when the sync was aborted the names of the songs appear, but the songs aren´t there.

Answer (score 0):

do you by a chance have a playlist ?
if so deleat it.
did you try do add some new songs ?
add a couple and see if they'll play

Comment: I do not have a playlist. All songs in a same list.

Comment: how do you add new songs ? ture itunes ? if so try deleting all your songs from the ipod and uload them again. don't forget to make a backup